# NestJS module at index 2 of "imports" array is undefined but there is no index 2?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, nestjs

Hello I have a problem with my NestJS project: when I try to compile it throws:

```
Nest cannot create the ChannelModule instance.
The module at index [2] of the ChannelModule "imports" array is undefined.
[...]
Scope [AppModule -> UserModule]
```

But I checked like 10 times and the imports are right, there are no circular imports, anyway there are only two elements in my `imports` so there is no such `index [2]`, and even when I delete all the code of my ChannelModule the same error appears, which makes no sense:
Here is the code for all my modules:

```js
// ./app.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import UserModule from './user/user.module';
import MessageModule from './message/message.module';
import ChannelModule from './channel/channel.module';
import ReceiverModule from './receiver/receiver.module';
import ScoreModule from './score/score.module';

@Module(
  {
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({
        envFilePath: '.env',
      }),
      TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        inject: [ConfigService],
        useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
          return {
            type: 'postgres',
            host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
            port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
            database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
            username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
            password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
            synchronize: true,
            autoLoadEntities: true,
          };
        },
      }),
      UserModule,
      MessageModule,
      ChannelModule,
      ReceiverModule,
      ScoreModule
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
  }
)
export default class AppModule {}
```

```js
// ./user/user.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import ReceiverModule from '../receiver/receiver.module';
import MessageModule from '../message/message.module';
import ScoreModule from '../score/score.module';
import ChannelModule from '../channel/channel.module';
import UserEntity from './user.entity';
import UserController from './user.controller';
import UserService from './user.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity]),
        ReceiverModule,
        MessageModule,
        ScoreModule,
        ChannelModule
    ],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService]
})
export default class UserModule {}
```

```js
// ./channel/channel.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import ChannelEntity from './channel.entity';
import ChannelService from './channel.service';
import ChannelController from './channel.controller';
import ReceiverModule from '../receiver/receiver.module';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ChannelEntity]),
        ReceiverModule
    ],
    controllers: [ChannelController],
    providers: [ChannelService],
    exports: [ChannelService,]
})
export default class ChannelModule {}
```

```js
// ./message/message.module.ts
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import MessageEntity from './message.entity';
import MessageController from './message.controller';
import MessageService from './message.service';
import ReceiverModule from '../receiver/receiver.module';

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([MessageEntity]),
        ReceiverModule
    ],
    controllers: [MessageController],
    providers: [MessageService],
    exports: [MessageService]
})
export default class MessageModule {}
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import ReceiverService from './receiver.service';
import ReceiverEntity from './receiver.entity';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ReceiverEntity])],
    providers: [ReceiverService],
    exports: [ReceiverService]
})
export default class ReceiverModule {}
```

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import ScoreService from './score.service';
import ScoreEntity from './score.entity';
import ScoreController from './score.controller';

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ScoreEntity])],
    controllers: [ScoreController],
    providers: [ScoreService],
    exports: [ScoreService]
})
export default class ScoreModule {}
```

Comment: btw you didn't saw anything on javascript compiler on this lol But yeah, typescript error messages could be hard do digest. Oh, this isn't a TS error msg, it just how the core team designed the error message for circular dependencies, feel free to improve that: https://github.com/nestjs/nest

Comment: @MicaelLevi By js and frameworks I mean mostly frameworks, but I dont see any circular dependancy in my code that's why I don't understand that error message

Comment: got it. I mean, the error msg looks pretty good to me tho, so idk. Anyway. Looks like this is a bug on the fw side. There's no reason to show `2` when there is only 2 elements in that array (which is 0-based). Please create a minimum repro (or just share the full project) and report it to them.

Comment: @MicaelLevi so there is no errors in the modules then, I have to use this framework for a school project so It's a little bit annoying to have to report this to the framework creators, It looks like the error comes from another part of my code, I'd like to fix it but the error log doesn't help

Comment: if you could share the full code here (or just with my github account: `@micalevisk`), I'll help you out.

Comment: you could also use the [Discord server](https://discord.gg/nestjs) there is dedicated for general free support

Comment: @MicaelLevi thanks, I pushed the code on github https://github.com/2LeoCode/ft_transcendance/tree/experimental (the nestjs part is located at https://github.com/2LeoCode/ft_transcendance/tree/experimental/site/back) To build the project go to `site` folder and run `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: you've made few changes. Can you run `rm -rf dist` and `npm run start` again, and share the error message you're getting now

Comment: @MicaelLevi Ok I don't understand what happened I just did git pull on the branch just after a git push with no modifications and now I have another error message x) I forgot the controller decorator on my UserController, It works now thanks but I don't know what the hell happened